# NoClassDefFoundError: HttpClient 4 (APACHE)

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-felix

I am using apache http commons 4.I have added both httpcore-4.0.1.jar and httpclient-4.0.1.jar in the classpath of netbeans. I am getting error:
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient**

My Code is as follows. Please help.

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HttpClientManager {
    public HttpClient httpclient;
    public HttpClientManager() {
        this.init();
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getCourseList() {
        String url = "http://exnet.in.th/api.php?username=demoinst&ha=2b62560&type=instructor";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            System.out.println(responseBody);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception happened because of Felix did not find the actual class as it was not included the import.
Thanks all for answering this.

OK I got it work by adding path of DefaultHttpClient to felix.properties –

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out `NoClassDefFoundError` and `NoClassFoundException` are not the one and the same thing?

You might want to look into [Demystified class loading problem series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=demystifying+class+loading+problems).

All the best.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError:
Yes it was NoClassDefFoundError
Thanks for help. problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

`httpclient-4.0.1.jar` contains `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` check your classpath for typos.

Comment: OK I got it work by adding path of DefaultHttpClient to felix.properties